# Setting up Azure SQL External Metastore for Azure Databricks — Invalid column name ‘IS_REWRITE_ENABLED’

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, databricks, azure-hdinsight, hive-metastore

I’m attempting to set up an external Hive metastore for Azure Databricks. The Metastore is in Azure SQL and the Hive version is 1.2.1 (included with azure HdInsight 3.6).

I have followed the setup instructions on the “[External Apache Hive metastore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/metastores/external-hive-metastore)” page in Azure documentation.

I can see all of the databases and tables in the metastore but if I look at a specific table I get the following.

```
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOException: Exception thrown when executing query : SELECT DISTINCT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MTable' AS NUCLEUS_TYPE,A0.CREATE_TIME,A0.LAST_ACCESS_TIME,A0.OWNER,A0.RETENTION,A0.IS_REWRITE_ENABLED,A0.TBL_NAME,A0.TBL_TYPE,A0.TBL_ID FROM TBLS A0 LEFT OUTER JOIN DBS B0 ON A0.DB_ID = B0.DB_ID WHERE A0.TBL_NAME = ? AND B0."NAME" = ?
NestedThrowables:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'IS_REWRITE_ENABLED'.
```

I was expecting to see errors relating to the underlying storage but this appears to be a problem with the metastore.

Anybody have any idea what’s wrong?

Comment: Please provide the output of Describe extended A0 and B0?

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to suggest that the column IS_REWRITE_ENABLED doesn't exist on table *TBLS* with alias *A0*.

Looking at the script for the hive-schema for the derby db, it can help guide you in seeing that the column in question does exist here.

[metastore script definition](https://github.com/apache/hive/commit/e3168cfc867a534d82e4fd6deef1ba4c4c5ed7c1)

If you've got admin access to the Azure SQL db, you can alter the table and add the column:

```
ALTER TABLE TBLS
ADD IS_REWRITE_ENABLED char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N';
```

I don't believe this is the actual fix but it does work around the error.